# How to create multiple persistence unit Names in JBoss7.1.1.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jboss7.x

I am upgrading jboss server 4.1.2 to jboss 7.1.1 so getting exception is

```
15:51:24,655 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mobeeadmin.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mobeeadmin.war".DEPENDENCIES: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "mobeeadmin.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_37]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 3 persistence unit definitions in application deployment "mobeeadmin.war".  Either change the application to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.resolvePersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.getPersistenceUnit(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:284)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.getBindingSource(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:220)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.processField(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:151)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.processPersistenceAnnotations(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.deploy(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

application environment is seam2.1.2 integrate with jpa ,richfaces and jsf.
how can i declare multiple persistence units in jboss 7.1.1.

my components.xml

```
<core:init debug="false" jndi-pattern="@jndiPattern@" transaction-management-   enabled="true"/>
<core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="2000"
    conversation-id-parameter="cid" conversation-timeout="120000"

<web:hot-deploy-filter url-pattern="/*.mobee" />


<persistence:entity-manager-factory
    installed="@seamBootstrapsPu@" name="entityManagerFactory"
    persistence-unit-name="pu1" />
<persistence:managed-persistence-context 
    auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="@seamEmfRef@" name="entityManager"
    persistence-unit-jndi-name="@puJndiName@" />

 <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="empEntityManagerFactory" 
                  persistence-unit-name="pu2"/>

    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="empEntityManager"
    auto-create="true" entity-manager-factory="#{empEntityManagerFactory}"
    persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/pu2Database"/>




<async:quartz-dispatcher />


<security:identity authenticate-method="#{authenticator.authenticate}" />


<web:rewrite-filter view-mapping="*.mobee" />

<event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn">
    <action execute="#{redirect.captureCurrentView}" />
</event>

<event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
    <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}" />
</event>
<mail:mail-session host="localhost" port="25" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/sample1</jta-data-source>

        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>


            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />


            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="@transactionManagerLookupClass@" />

          <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="@puJndiName@ "/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="pu2" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/sample2</jta-data-source>

        <mapping-file>META-INF/emp2Orm.xml</mapping-file>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>


            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />


                <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />


               <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/pu2Database" />



        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I followed the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23299991/4635485 and had the problem solved. :)

Answer (score 11):

I was doing the same. I was moving my spring application to Jboss 8 (WildFly). I got the same error. After googling for few hours, at last I found the solution.

Go to \\standalone\configuration.

Open standalone.xml. and Look for

subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1

Comment that tag, and restart the server. It should work now.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will gest than the entity manager is injected by JBoss by-passing the Seam injection mechanime.

[It seems to get seam 2 working on JBoss 7 you need to make some changes](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Example+Applications+-+Migrated+to+AS7)

[And I find another one that seems to ask JBoss to don't care about JPA](http://www.solutionsfit.com/2012/10/19/upgrading-a-seam-2-app-to-jboss-7/)

The other solution will be to upgrade to Seam 3.