# Spring JPA configuration issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have gone through almost all the posts here regarding Spring JPA configuration. Basically I want to implement JPA Pagination in my project and for that I need spring JPA support. But when I include the `spring-data-jpa.jar` in my project I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment deployment "CPCardApp.ear".  Either change the application deployment to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.ambiguousPUError(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findWithinDeployment(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findWithinApplication(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:86)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findPersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.resolvePersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:63)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.getPersistenceUnit(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:357)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.getBindingSource(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.processMethod(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:201)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.processPersistenceAnnotations(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.deploy(JPAAnnotationParseProcessor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 5 more
```

**persistence.xml** (Note: I have 2 persistence units in my xml and Spring doesn't support that)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="data01">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDataDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="cpaudit">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlAuditDS</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The error message seems to be quite clear. Which part of it does confuse you?

Comment: What application server?

Comment: @JustinKSU It's Jboss as metionned `at org.jboss`

Comment: This answer will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522478/how-to-create-multiple-persistence-unit-names-in-jboss7-1-1-final/23299991#23299991

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 persistence units. There are problems with your config (combo of using JBoss + Spring + JPA (Hibernate) + JTA). The proper configuration will depend on your version of JBoss and Spring.
No matter what you will need to have an xml file to define your JPA config with two entity managers.

Try something like this in a application-jpa-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:transaction="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
    <beans>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactorData01" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <map>
                    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value-ref="jtaPlatform"/>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
            <property name="jtaDataSource">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
                    <property name="password" value="${database.data01.password}"/>
                    <property name="url" value="${database.data01.url}"/>
                    <property name="username" value="${database.data01.user}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.entites.data01"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactoryCpaudit"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <map>
                    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
                    <entry key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value-ref="jtaPlatform"/>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
            <property name="jtaDataSource">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
                    <property name="password" value="${database.cpaudit.password}"/>
                    <property name="url" value="${database.cpaudit.url}"/>
                    <property name="username" value="${database.cpaudit.user}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.entites.cpaudit"/>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" id="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </bean>

        <context:annotation-config/>

        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repo.data01" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactorData01"/>
        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repo.cpaudit" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryCpaudit"/>


        <!-- ************ JpaTransactionManager *********** -->
        <!--
            This will depend on your JBoss and Spring version and your application.
            You will need to work this out.
            Getting your transactionManager correct could be difficult.
            See the following project for more ideas:
            https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-jta/blob/master/src/main/resources/springContext.xml
        -->
        <transaction:annotation-driven/>

        <bean class="java.lang.String" id="jtaPlatform">
            <constructor-arg value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
            <property name="transactionManager">
                <bean class="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple"/>
            </property>
            <property name="userTransaction">
                <bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction" factory-method="userTransaction"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <!-- ************ JpaTransactionManager *********** -->

    </beans>
</beans>
```